# getType() in JDialog cannot override getType() in Window

Tags: java, swing, java-7

```
private int buType=0;
public int getType()
{
    return buType;
}
```

The ablove snippet was written in a class extending the JDialog class. It was compiling fine with Java1.6 but when I tried compiling it with JAva1.7, it is giving the error as "getType() in JDialog cannot override getType() in Window"

getType() is now officially a part of Window Class and it returns an enum type value.

What changes should I do to remove this compilation error. Should I refactor the getType() method or should I take the output of getType() in an enum variable and then cast it to variable(buType).

PS-I need the output in 'int' type only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way is to change your method `getType()` to some other name (`getTypes()` or else) because `getType()` method is added to the `Window class` in Java 7.

`Window` is the parent class of the `JDialog` so when you do `getType(){}` then you are trying to override it. Hence you are getting error.

Comment: Is there a specific functionality of getType() in JDialog which would get affected if I change the method name to getTypes() ??? Please confirm.

Comment: @user3024326 Try it and see.